# id of a link that a function is called from

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, greasemonkey, event-listener

I hope it's not a problem to post much specific code here, but I figure it will be better explained if everyone can just see it, so I will give you my code and then I will explain my problem.

My code:

```
function addBeGoneLinks () {
     var beGoneClassElems;
     var beGoneSpan;
     var beGoneLink;
     var beGonePrintSafe;
     var spacesSpan;
     //var middotSpan = document.createElement ('span');

     var interactionContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('feedItemInteractionContainer');

     for (var i=0; i<children.length; i++)
     {
         beGonePrintSafe = false;

         beGoneClassElems = children[i].getElementsByClassName('beGone')

         beGonePrintSafe = true;


         if (beGoneClassElems.length == 0)
         {
             beGoneLink = document.createElement('a');
             beGoneLink.href = 'javascript:void(0);';
             beGoneLink.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Be Gone'));
             beGoneLink.className = 'beGone';
             beGoneLink.id = 'beGoneLink' + i.toString();
             beGoneLink.addEventListener ("click", function() {beGone();}, false);//This line!
             beGoneLink.align = 'right';

             spacesSpan = document.createElement('span');
             spacesSpan.innerHTML = ' - ';

             if (interactionContainer[i] != undefined)
             {
                 interactionContainer[i].appendChild(spacesSpan);
                 interactionContainer[i].appendChild(beGoneLink);
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Here I have a function from a Greasemonkey script that I am working on. When one of the links is clicked, my aim is to have it call the function `beGone()` which will, among other things, remove the whole element a few parents up, thereby removing their sibling's, their parents and their parents' siblings, and one or two levels after that.

My idea was just to get the id of the link that was pressed and pass it to `beGone()` so that I could then get the parents using its id, but I do not know how to do that. Am I able to have the id of a link passed by the function that it calls? If not, is there any other way to do this?

I am not sure whether I am missing some really simple solution, but I haven't been able to find one rooting around the web, especially because I was unsure how I would search for this specific problem.

Comment: pass "this" as an argument with the function and try to get id of that element(here the link)

Comment: I had a feeling it would have something to do with "this". So only the keyword "this", nothing else?

Comment: In the context of the event, `this` should be the element that was clicked. Not all elements have id's so don't expect ID's to be your solution.

Comment: for getting parent you can use something like this..var parentId = $(ele).parent().get(0).id;..where ele is "this" element

Comment: Okay, thank you guys, but I know that these have id's, as I assigned id's to them. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
beGoneLink.addEventListener("click", beGone, false);

beGone = function (evt) {
    evt.target; // evt.target refers to the clicked element.
       ...
}
```

You can then use `evt.target.id`, `evt.target.parentNode`, etc.

Comment: +1 correct approach.  Added a little; edit it back out if you object.

Comment: Thanks, I was considering to add something like you have added, but there are so many further references in the question...

Comment: PS:  The first line can be simplified to `beGoneLink.addEventListener ("click", beGone, false);`.  The event parameter is passed automatically.  This approach also reduces potential memory leaks.

Comment: @BrockAdams You're right, fixed that. I was too stucked to the OP's original code.